# Do you need to understand tensor calculus in order to use TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

It might sound like a dumb question, but I like asking such. Do you need to understand tensor calculus in order to use the Google framework TensorFlow? Can someone purely from programming background take full advantage of it without fully understanding intricacies of tensor calculus?

Comment: The simple answer is yes.  The more complicated one is that it depends on your use case. If you specifically need to do tensor calculus then tensorflow won't save you from learning to do it.

Comment: Thanks that helps. How about from deep learning perspective?

Comment: the name is a misnomer, there aren't really any tensors in TF, it should be called ArrayFlow, arrays you should definitely understand

Comment: Yes of course, arrays make sense.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Watch this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f5liqUk0ZTw) on "What's a tensor" ...basically as the comments have said tensors are "multidimensional arrays". I would say, per this [math exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1134809/are-there-any-differences-between-tensors-and-multidimensional-arrays) post that:

> a tensor is a type of multidimensional array with certain
>   transformation properties

So "calculus"? ...hmm, rather I would say be solid on your linear algebra to get the most out of Tensorflow! Good luck!